# Mediafire image direct link ( convkey ) from api

Tags: mediafire

how i can get a direct link to img from MediaFire api?

the normal_download and the view tags contain a link that redirect to 
mf site for view the image..

es: 
[indirect img](http://www.mediafire.com/view/6xp6kii7kua2g8p/golem.jpeg)
[direct https://www.mediafire.com/convkey/dab1/n9yn9o1dv9d1er86g.jpg](https://www.mediafire.com/convkey/dab1/n9yn9o1dv9d1er86g.jpg)

for getting a direct link through script ( js ), i must request direct_download page and after i have to get the direct link ( convkey ) with regx.

This is very slow and awful solution.. alternative?

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with a list of items returned by the 'folder/get_content' API (for example), this is very easy to do:

http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/[hash]/[quickkey].jpg?size_id=[size_id]

Where:

hash = first 4 bytes of the file's hash

quickkey = quickkey

size_id = the requested image size as shown on the Image Conversion API documentation

http://www.mediafire.com/developers/media_api/images/